# Disable Setting Windows 10 Background Image Through The Right-Click Menu

Tags: windows-10, images, background

So in windows 10(any version tbh), if you have 15 images selected like this: [15 Images = "Edit Menu"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB6sj.png)

Pressing enter will do the same as the R-Click Menu Item at the top, which is `Edit` in this case, which means they'll be opened in my default photo editor(PaintDotNet in this case).

However if you have 16 or more images selected the top R-Click Menu Item has now become `Set as desktop background`,
See this image for an example: [16+ Images = "Set as desktop background"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U742P.png)

So pressing enter with 16 or more images selected will do the same as the R-Click Menu Item at the top,
but why on earth would anyone want this?

So my question is:
How do I disable this, I just wanted to be able to open my images without having to drag and drop it into PaintDotNet ;-;

Found a solution:
Inside the `Registry Editor` go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` and add a `DWORD (32-bit) Value` and call it `MultipleInvokePromptMinimum`, double click to edit it and set it to a decimal value of your choice.

With this you could both increase and decrease this limit

Comment: But I can select 17 images (all Jpeg) and still no such thing happens. I can open them all at once in the windows default photo viewer.

Comment: I've had this issue for a really long time, but what Windows Version do you use?
I just checked mine, it's Windows 10 Home specifically

Comment: Yeah, mine's also Windows 10 Home. But the problem that you are saying is li'l weird. Would be great if you send those some 20  pictures, I will cross check.

Comment: Don't mind sending them, but it's not specifically with these images, if I were to do this with other game textures or normal photos, the problem would still occur at 16+ Images

Comment: I think that has something to do with your photoviewer. Perhaps, it can't open more than 16 images at once. Try changing picture viewer to windows default viewer if you have some other sofwares installed for the purpose.

Comment: @Sanu_012
That's actually it, I've always use PaintDotNet on every PC I had so I never realized that it was actuall because of PaintDotNet, if I set the default photoviewer to just the default photoviewer I can select more than 16 images and it does **not** set it as my background anymore:
https://i.imgur.com/I4N6q7O.png

Still want PDN to be my default photo"viewer" though, I guess I'll make some batch script that opens images in PDN and make that batch file the default application